# Is a permanent sukkah OK?

Tags: sukkah

Some people build permanent sukkot in their backyards.  Is this OK?  If not, how much of the sukkah must actually be built prior to the holiday?

Comment: If the "sukkah rooms" in some houses are kosher, then it is all about the schach (which can't be old)

Comment: There's a gemarrah where a guy removes the roofing from his house and replaces it with schach and it's deemed kosher. Shanah tovah, @Maurice!

Comment: @JoshK --   גם לך

Comment: The schach must be moved around within 30 days of succos for it to be kosher. The frames and walls can be left up all year.

Comment: The Bostoner Rebbe's dining room has a retractable roof which is removed for Sukkos and replaced with schach (source: I've eaten by him)